# how to access c++ memory mapped files in java

Tags: java, c++, interop, memory-mapped-files

I have a windows c++ application that creates a memory mapped file for a bitmap that is updated frequently. I would like to access to this memory mapped file to display the live image in a java application. How can I do that?

I know that FileChannel can be mapped to memory but I cannot see how to access a memory mapped file created by another process.

I already use JNA in my java application, should I use it to access standard windows memory mapped files functionality?

Or do you have any other solution than the memory mapped file to display a live image stream in java from an image created by a separate program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finaly used [jna](http://jna.dev.java.net) and the *platform* library that they provide. The [Kernel32](https://jna.dev.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32.html) package offers access to the *CreateFileMapping* and *MapViewOfFile* functions.

Comment: the provided link for jna is broken

Answer (score 2):

There is a code sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/sharedmem_jni.aspx) that does what you want using JNI to bridge from C++ (Win32 memory mapped files) to Java.  Might just work as is, although some cleanup for security and threading might be needed depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A memory mapped file is still a file. You could read it with java.io, or you could use a MappedByteBuffer from java.nio if you want it memory-mapped in Java too.